# How to Update fragment when values in other fragments are changing

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to draw a graph in a fragment with values that I am computing in another fragment.
The other fragment is changing static variables in a class (AnalysedTweet) which are being used in the fragment to draw the graph.

Is there a way to update the graph? (Update the fragment with the graph on it)

This is my code for the graph fragment:

```
public class Statistics extends Fragment {

    GraphicalView mChartView= null;
    private DefaultRenderer mRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();
    private CategorySeries mSeries = new CategorySeries("Sentiment");
    private int[] COLORS = new int[] {Color.parseColor("#009900"),Color.RED, Color.GRAY};

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_statistics,  container, false);
        int[] count = new int[3];
        count[0] = AnalysedTweet.getCount_pos();
        count[1] = AnalysedTweet.getCount_neg();
        count[2] = AnalysedTweet.getCount_obj();

        String[] categoryNames = {"Positive","Negative","Objective" };
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){

        mSeries.add(categoryNames[i], count[i]);
        SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(COLORS[i]);
        renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

        }


        mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this.getActivity(), mSeries, mRenderer);

        Log.i("CHART", Integer.toString(mSeries.getItemCount()));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mChartView.setLayoutParams(params);
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chartsRelativeLayout);
        layout.addView(mChartView);

        return rootView;
    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could do this with a broadcast receiver? http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should never use static variables (aka globals) for communication, thats really bad practice. This is the way google advises on this matter:

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for
>   example to change the content based on a user event. All
>   Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.
>   To allow a Fragment to communicate up to its Activity, you can define
>   an interface in the Fragment class and implement it within the
>   Activity. The Fragment captures the interface implementation during
>   its onAttach() lifecycle method and can then call the Interface
>   methods in order to communicate with the Activity.
>
> Here is an example of Fragment to Activity communication:

public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
        OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

```
    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

see more heree http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html